# Definition of non-interacting particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, interactions

A system of non-interacting particles is equal to a system of free particles that is equal to an ideal gas?

Answer (score 1):

No, a system of non-interacting particles could still follow the "pull/push" of a common potential, they would not necessarily be free, as in the sense of free electrons. Free usually assumes totally without constraint.

An ideal gas is simply that, a model, not a totally realistic scenario, but it's a very good approximation if the size of the particles is much less than the mean free path.  (And it's handy for teaching thermodynamics and statistical mechanics as well).

I hope you raise the objection that there is no such thing as a free particle either, because that's an idealisation as well, but in the context of your post, we assume free **means** free.

Comment: then the free particles have potential energy U = 0 while non-interacting particles can have U different from 0?

Comment: yes, bearing in mind the caveats above.